# Linking error libboost_system with tabletop_object_detector

Tags: tabletop-object-detector, ubuntu, ubuntu-oneiric, linking, libboost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I decided to upgrade my laptop to Oneiric today and after fixing quite a few new issues, I'm stuck on an issue I can't seem to get fixed. When rosmaking tabletop_object_detector I get the following error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/tabletop_object_recognition.dir/src/tabletop_object_recognition.o: undefined reference to symbol 'boost::system::system_category()'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'boost::system::system_category()' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.46.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.46.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
```

I tried various things, from reinstalling libboost1.46-all-dev to making with --pre-clean, nothing seemed to have helped.

Can anyone help me out with this probably minor issue?

ps. I'm still running ROS Electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32914/linking-error-libboost_system-with-tabletop_object_detector/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2012-04-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I (hack)fixed it for now by adding -lboost_system to the target_link_libraries for tabletop_object_recognition, but it still beats me why this started to give errors now ...

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2012-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Loy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1830/loy/) on 2012-06-20**:
I fixed it by adding set(CXX_FLAGS "-lboost_system") to CMakeLists.txt on Ubuntu 11.10